# PHP / SQL Group Rows and Sum Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where I need to group users together and then sum the invoice amount into a total. I just cannot seem to figure an elegant way of doing this, I tried iterating though a while loop using each usersID via an IF statement but this method would not be practical as each new user added later would require a new if statement to be added.

SQL Example

```
UserID  Invoice  InvoiceAMT
 419       1       20.00
 419       2       30.99
 420       3       30.00
 421       4        1.00
 419       5       60.00
```

What I want to return is

```
UserID   Total Invoices   Total Amount
 419           3            110.99
 420           1             30.00
 421           1              1.00
```

Comment: This is a basic aggregation query.  You should learn the basics if you are going to use SQL.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: or with an example http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with `SUM()`

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(Invoice) `Total Invoices`, SUM(InvoiceAMT) `Total Amount`
FROM table
GROUP BY UserID
```

Column names with spaces are bad so avoid them. For example instead of `Total Invoices` you should use `TotalInvoices` or `Total_Invoices`

Comment: You sure `SUM` is appropriate for `Total Invoices`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish No it wasn't, I think count is more appropriate.

Comment: I did try using aggregate functions, however even as above my code still produces a row for each row rather than grouping all the same userID's together.

Comment: @Seth Did you use `GROUP BY UserID`?

Comment: I did, but it still returns;169-1-4.0000
169-1-4.0000
169-1-4.0000
169-1-4.5000
169-1-4.5000
169-2-9.0000
169-1-15.0000
169-1-15.0000
169-1-37.5000
169-1-40.0000
169-1-89.0000
169-1-89.0000
169-1-89.0000
169-1-89.0000
169-2-178.0000
169-3-267.0000
169-6-534.0000

Comment: Not to worry, it was an issue with my query. I had more than one group by parameter as I was using HAVING to filter my results